# AlarmManager alarm start when system time is changed by user?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i am using **AlarmManager** class for setting Alarms it is working fine.

But if i set alarm like 9pm and current time  is 8pm and i changed  the system time to 10pm
then alarm 9pm alarm start automatically. so to solve this issue

**i have searched so much but did not found any good answer**
Please help

here is my code for alarm setting

```
    final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("requestCode", id);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: this is not phisible

Comment: What do you want to solve? There is no problem. All alarms that are needed to be called previously are called immediately. Specify you question

Comment: when i changed system time greater than alarm time then alarm start Ringing

Comment: @HappyRahal what would you like to happen when you change the time?

Comment: if i set alarm for 7 pm and i changed system time to 10 pm then alarm of 7pm is start ringing immediately at 10pm

Comment: @HappyRahal yeah, i understand that, but what would you like to happen instead?

Comment: @user13 i want if time is changed then alarm not rings and will be scheduled for next day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options is to store all set alarms in database, then create a BroadcastReceiver which will listen for `ACTION_TIME_CHANGE` action. When user changes time it will be triggered. Then create a `IntentService` which will be responsible for resetting alarms. In this service class:

1. Read db and identify all passed alarms.
2. Cancel passed alarms
3. Set alarms for next day

Your code may look like as below:

In your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_TIME_CHANGE"/>
```

and below activities:

```
 <receiver android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver" android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

 <service android:name=".RestartAlarmsService"/>
```

Create class "TimeChangedReceiver" inside of which:

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if("android.intent.action.TIME_SET".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, RestartAlarmsService.class);
            ComponentName service = context.startService(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Create "RestartAlarmsService" class inside of which:

```
public class RestartAlarmsService extends IntentService {

    public RestartAlarmsService() {
        super("RestartAlarmsService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // read db here
        // then cancel passed alarms
        // reset them to next day
    }
}
```

You can find many tutorials on how to use Databases and implement it in your code. Hope my answer is somehow helpful.

Comment: yes i am storing alarms Detail in ArrayList of custom type and then storing this arraylist in sharedprefrence

Comment: Then simply read it inside of Service and identify which alarms are need to be reset.

Comment: It is a common practice to do such actions using Service. BroadCastReceivers are used to do small amount of work. Any other tasks are advised to be left for Services. Moreover, `IntentService` will run in background in parallel and finish itself when the job is done so no need to worry about its lifecycle.

Comment: @HappyRahal then consider accepting and upvoting my answer

Comment: Service is working fine and but Alarm Still running     this is my code for canceling alarms                                                                                                                `code` public void cancelAlarm(Context c,int reqCode) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(c,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c,reqCode,intent,0);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);

        Log.i("Alarm", reqCode + "canceled");

    }

Comment: I printed logs than i see that BroadcastReceiver for alarm is running before TimeChangedReceiver and Service. therefore alarm still rings what can i do here please help @Marat

Comment: @HappyRahal When setting alarm, what if you will pass the time as extra to intent and then check every alarm for time in your BroadcastReceiver for alarms? Include if statement and turn on ring and other things if and only If the time in extra is not passed? That way you will have enough time to cancel and reset alarms

Comment: but what is reason of Alarm Receiver rings before ResetingService i think i am performing alarm Ringing task inside BroadcatsReceiver  .may be needed to performed inside service. because TimeChanged  receiver runs before servce and alarm receiver @Marat

Comment: @HappyRahal In the documentation it is written that after changing time all alarms that are passed their time will be triggered immideately. There is no gurantee that Resetting Service will be always triggered first. What I recommend is to include `if/else` inside of Alarm Receiver, so that passed alarms will not wake phone up and ring.

Comment: ok i Understand..so.. what i put inside if/else mean what is to check @Marat

Comment: @HappyRahal yes, you need to first extract time from intent and then check it in parameters of if statement. If time is not passed yet, let's say 30 min ago or more, then it is ok and allow ringing, else do nothing

Comment: ok i will try ..thanks for your answers ..@Marat and so now i not need TImeChange Receiver

Comment: comparison not working with date change correctly can you  please help @Marat

Comment: did  I need to give special permission for date change @Marat

Comment: @HappyRahal I advice to post it as a seperate question with the code and detailed errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

yes it will give you broadcast, as your pending intent object is still attached to that event while you change time that is greater than you alarm firing time.

solution- validate your condition while you receive broadcast from alarm manager